# ajax call from loop in asp.net

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax

GetDataStudentPDF() call a webmethods and gets list of items, each item is a html script. I just want to set that script to a div and then calling the another SaveImage() function which converts the div to image and save it. It should happen for each items

```
function SaveImage(i, lastI) {
           $('#divStdTemplate').html2canvas({

               onrendered: function (canvas) {

                   var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace(/^data[:]image\/(png|jpg|jpeg)[;]base64,/i, "");

                   $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "SliderPage.aspx/StudentPopUpUploadImage",
                       data: JSON.stringify({ imageData: img }),
                       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                       dataType: 'json',
                       async: false,
                       success: function (response) {

                       },
                       failure: function (response) {
                           alert("html2canvas Fail");
                       },
                       error: function (response) {
                           alert("html2canvas Error * " + response.error + " * " + response.responseText);
                       }
                   });

               }
           });

       }
    function GetDataStudentPDF()
       {
           var cnt1 = 0;
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: 'SliderPage.aspx/GetDataStudentPDF',
               data: JSON.stringify({}),
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType: 'json',
               async: true,
               success: function (response) {

                   var data = response.d;

                   $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                       $("#divStdTemplate").html(item);
                       SaveImage();

                   });

               },
               failure: function (response) {
               alert("Fail");
           },
           error: function (response) {
               alert(response);
           }

           });

       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could recursively call a function which would do the ajax call. This would ensure that the next iteration is not called until the success case.

*Note that in this context, if any call fails or has an error, execution will stop.

**Update 1**

Because this is highly reliant on your implementation, this can't be tested outside of your system, but the issue was that you were not calling SaveImage recursively (you were still calling every iteration at once).

Here's an idea of how to call it recursively:

```
var dataStudentArray = [];

function SaveImage(i) {
  $('#divStdTemplate').html2canvas({
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
      var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace(/^data[:]image\/(png|jpg|jpeg)[;]base64,/i, "");

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "SliderPage.aspx/StudentPopUpUploadImage",
        data: JSON.stringify({ imageData: img }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function (response) {
          //successfully Saved Image
          $("#divStdTemplate").html(response.d);

          //call next iteration if not last
          if(i < (dataStudentArray.length - 1)) {
            SaveId(i+1);
          }
        },
        failure: function (response) {
          alert("html2canvas Fail");
        },
        error: function (response) {
          alert("html2canvas Error * " + response.error + " * " + response.responseText);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}

function GetDataStudentPDF()
{
  var cnt1 = 0;
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'SliderPage.aspx/GetDataStudentPDF',
    data: JSON.stringify({}),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,
    success: function (response) {
        //set output as array (depending on your data, you may need to iterate through the data and add each item to the dataStudentArray)
      dataStudentArray = response.d;

      //save the first item
      SaveImage(0);
    },
    failure: function (response) {
      alert("Fail");
    },
    error: function (response) {
      alert(response);
    }

  });

}

//get all data
GetDataStudentPDF();
```

Here's a simple JSFiddle to show this: https://jsfiddle.net/2yxg2r0o/2/

**Update 0**

```
SaveId = function(i, lastI) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'SliderPage.aspx/SetDataStudentPDF',
    data: JSON.stringify({ jd: i }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function (response) {
      $("#divStdTemplate").html(response.d);
      SaveImage();
      if(i<lastI-1) {
        SaveId(i+1, lastI);
      }
    },
    failure: function (response) {
      alert("myfunction Fail");
    },
    error: function (response) {
      alert("myfunction error ** " + response.status + " -- " + response.statusCode + " -- " + response.statusText);
    }
  });
}

SaveId(0, 2);
```

Here's a JSFiddle to show the code flow simply: https://jsfiddle.net/2yxg2r0o/

Comment: Thanks for your effort Jem, but still having same async call,means if I want to update html ' $("#divStdTemplate").html(response.d)'  and call SaveImage() 21 times,then the issue is it calls the SaveImage() 21 times at once at the end and for all 21 times the 'divStdTemplate' has the same html.

Comment: The success function won't be called until the ajax call returns successful, so the next iteration of SaveId won't be called until the previous one is successful. I've added a delay here which should simulate the results https://jsfiddle.net/2yxg2r0o/1/ . Can you show me how you implemented it to give more information?

Comment: Hi Jem, Thanks, I have added full code hope will help you to understand

Comment: See update 1 above. The issue you were having is that you were still not calling SaveImage recursively. You need to call the function for the next iteration from within itself in the Success function of the SaveImage ajax call.

Comment: Jem, Thanks for your consistent effort, it is working now. Am calling the SaveImage() once from GetDataStudentPDF's success before it adding the responses to array as you suggested and SaveImage() has loop to call itself . Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome. Please mark this as answer, and I'm glad it's working for you!